# How do I stop customers on Magento from using the same email on different store views?

Tags: php, email

I have a wholesale and retail version of my store. I have these setup on Magento as different store views, which means they can access the same database, which makes it simple to stock manage etc.

My problem is that my customers are able to sign up using the same email across both stores.

We do not want this as it can cause confusion.

Is there any way to disable a user signing up again with the same email?

The only instance that the user is can't sign up with the same email is when they try to sign up on the same store E.G Wholesale .

However if a customer signed up to wholesale using the email hello@example.com. They could then sign up to the retail using hello@example.com.

Is there any way we can fix this as it is causing major inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Might be a late response, but if you set up your customer account sharing option to global from admin, customers won't be able to sign up for different stores via single email address. You can set this via

> System -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration ->
>   Account Sharing Options

Set this value to Global and you should be good to go.